# Apache mod_wsgi: PermissionError when trying to access a page

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

Trying to get Django running on this Apache box, using Python 3.3

`httpd` starts without fault but as soon as I try to access `localhost`, I am thrown a 500 error. The Apache logs say this:

```
[Wed Aug 20 13:50:24 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/__init__.py'
[Wed Aug 20 13:50:26 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=691): Target WSGI script '/var/www/tabstat/projet_tabstat/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Wed Aug 20 13:50:26 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=691): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/tabstat/projet_tabstat/wsgi.py'.
[Wed Aug 20 13:50:26 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Aug 20 13:50:26 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/var/www/tabstat/projet_tabstat/wsgi.py", line 13, in <module>
[Wed Aug 20 13:50:26 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Wed Aug 20 13:50:26 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1565, in _find_and_load
[Wed Aug 20 13:50:26 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1532, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Wed Aug 20 13:50:26 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 584, in _check_name_wrapper
[Wed Aug 20 13:50:26 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1022, in load_module
[Wed Aug 20 13:50:26 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1003, in load_module
[Wed Aug 20 13:50:26 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 560, in module_for_loader_wrapper
[Wed Aug 20 13:50:26 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 853, in _load_module
[Wed Aug 20 13:50:26 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 977, in get_code
[Wed Aug 20 13:50:26 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1031, in get_data
[Wed Aug 20 13:50:26 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/__init__.py'
```

I tried `chmod 777 __init__.py` but it didn't change anything. Wondering what could cause such an error...

Comment: Did you install django as a super user using sudo?

Comment: You could try to check whether apache has sufficient permissions for django in the shell by doing something like `sudo -u httpd python -c "import django"`.

Comment: The directories as well as files need to be readable to the user that Apache runs your code as.

Comment: I found out it was `SELinux` not trusting the file for some reason...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out it was `SELinux` not trusting the file for some reason.

Comment: im facing the same problem, how did you made SELinux to trust the file ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of disabling selinux run this:

```
restorecon -R /path/to/your/project/
restorecon -R /path/to/python/site-packages/
chcon -u system_u  /path/to/your/project/ -R 
chcon -u system_u  /path/to/python/site-packages/ -R
chown apache.apache /path/to/your/project/ -R
chown apache.apache /path/to/python/site-packages/ -R

# Remember to restart apache
systemctl restart httpd.service
```